# Signature capture on windows mobile java application

Tags: java, windows-mobile, native-code

The company I work for has an java application that runs on esmertec jbed JVM on windows mobile 6.

There is a requirement to capture a user's signature as part of some new functionality. One option is to try and implement this in java. This has been tried previously and has been found to be a bit slow.

I think the better option would be to get a native component to handle the drawing of the signature and save it to file. Does anyone know of a component that I would be able to use?

Creating our own component is an option as well but if there is one available already, I would prefer to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, I'll answer my own question.

I could not find an existing component that done this. We ended up writing some c++ code that would handle this.

The code would get a handle to the Java canvas and register our own callback function with it. This callback function would record any mouse movement within the canvas and draw a line when necessary (either on mouse up or after a number of points had been drawn). Once the user leaves the screen we would save the canvas to file and re-register the original canvas callback function.